# Vue Electron, devtools throwing exception

Tags: vue.js, electron, google-chrome-devtools

Literally out of the blue, I've started getting the following console message when i run `npm run dev`

```sh
[8492:0407/121603.977907:ERROR:CONSOLE(7830)] "Extension server error: Object not found: <top>", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (7830)
```

and my Electron Vue application doesn't finish loading, i just get a white screen. I've read around for several hours on the subject but found nothing that solves the problem.

I'm running on Ubuntu 16;  To be honest, I don't know what other details would be useful; Everything was behaving perfectly, then it simply wasn't...

I'm using the boilerplate at: https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

Answer (score 2):

Accroding to [this issue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/389),in index.dev.js

```
- require('electron-debug')({ showDevTools: true });
+ // Don't open dev tools with this, it is causing the error
+ require('electron-debug')();
```

in index.js

```
+  // Open dev tools initially when in development mode
+  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
+    mainWindow.webContents.on("did-frame-finish-load", () => {
+      mainWindow.webContents.once("devtools-opened", () => {
+        mainWindow.focus();
+      });
+      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
+    });
+  }
```

Comment: This also fixed a similar problem in non-Vue Electron apps. When my error occured, most of the React app still loads.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and do not know why,but I think it's the devtool's problem,so I remove the index.dev.js and it just be solved

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have created multiple live expressions in chrome console by pressing the eye icon and left them empty. Live expressions are used to track a variable's value for debugging purposes.

[image]

This happens usually when you try to clean up the console output.